# bluetooth headset for xbox that uses iphone microphone and speakers

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headset

Is it possible to create a bluetooth headset (for xbox) which would use the iphone for the microphone and the iphone speakers for the speakers?

Comment: Would this project entail rubber banding an iPhone to the user's head?

Answer (score 2):

No - It is not possible for the phone to act like a headset because it requires opposite role of the profile.
For Stereo audio streaming - Headsets suport the A2DP sink role and the phones are typically only A2DP source.
For voice audio - Headsets support the HSP/HFP profile's Handsfree / Headset Role roles and Phones are only the HFP/HSP Profile's Audio Gateway role.
iPhone is only Audio Gateway and A2DP source.

Comment: iPhone supports HFP. Check these link - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647, http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3621. Can you please confirm again?.

Comment: I clarified by answer - The HFP/HSP profile has 2 roles - Handsfree/Headset role and Audio Gateway role. The iPhone supports the HFP/HSP Profile's Audio Gateway role only.

Comment: I am confused now :) So to put things in a simplified manner, the iPhone can only be used as an Audio streaming source and as a gateway between applications and the bluetooth device. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently its possible to WIFI connect it 
http://www.dolejsky.com/remote-mic/

hardware connections for audio might get a little pricy/ time consuming with development kits: 
http://www.lemosint.com/bluetooth/bluetooth_oem_kits.php